# FindAndModify() in MongoDb does not return changed document

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using `FindAndModify` to modify a document.

The document is of type `User` and the element to modify is called `web`:

```
var users = _db.GetCollection<User>(UserCollectionName);

var userQuery = Query.EQ("user", "testuser");

var findAndModifyResult = users.FindAndModify(
       new FindAndModifyArgs()
       {
           Query = userQuery,
           Update = Update.Set("web", "testweb")   
       });

// user.web is unchanged in the result
var user = findAndModifyResult.GetModifiedDocumentAs<User>();

// user.web is changed in the result
user = users.FindOne(userQuery);
```

`GetModifiedDocumentAs()` doesn't return the changed instance, `user.web` still has the same value it had before the update.

When I query the `user` with `FindOne()` I see the changed value.

Is there something I need to take care of, so that `FindAndModify()` returns the modified document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query with : `{safe: true, 'new' : true}`

I'm not sure how to send these options in the c# driver.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#findandmodify-method

Looks like the final argument is the "new" option.

Comment: thanks, that works! I couldn't find the safe flag, it did work without it.

Comment: Yeah, I think with mongodb 2.6 the 'safe' command is turned on by default.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on Will Shavers' answer, this is the correct method with the c# driver:

```
collection.FindAndModify(
   new FindAndModifyArgs()
   {
       Query = query,
       Update = updateOperation,
       // this needs to be set
       VersionReturned = FindAndModifyDocumentVersion.Modified

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

To use [FindAndModifyArgs](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindAndModifyArgs.htm) is the correct way. All overloads of this method except this are deprecated from version 2.0. Here's an example where we find an object having the field IsBusy to false, and we change it to true, then we return it:

```
FindAndModifyArgs findAndModifyArgs;
FindAndModifyResult mongoResponse;
IMongoQuery   mongoQuery      = Query.EQ  ("IsBusy", false);
UpdateBuilder updateStatement = Update.Set("IsBusy", true);

// Finding a not busy app, and updating it to busy.
findAndModifyArgs = new FindAndModifyArgs()
{
    Query           = mongoQuery,
    Update          = updateStatement,
    SortBy          = null,
    VersionReturned = FindAndModifyDocumentVersion.Modified
 };
mongoResponse = _database.GetCollection<QueuedApp>(collectionName).FindAndModify(findAndModifyArgs);
return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<QueuedApp>(mongoResponse.ModifiedDocument);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.10.2, the method is called `FindOneAndUpdate` and you have to pass as last parameter

```
new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<T> { ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After }
```